# JSP Displays raw code when running in apache tomcat server

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat

```
    <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;" %>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <html>
       <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Service Provider</title>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" 
      />
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="css/round-about.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
   <body>
    <%
        int count=0;
                     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbase","root","");
                     Statement st= con.createStatement();
                     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from requests");
    %>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="top">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="header">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="menu">
                   <ul>
                        <li><a href="Admin.jsp">Add Car</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Delete.jsp">View Service Request</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Update.jsp">Update Request</a></li>
                        <li><a href="View.jsp">View Transactions</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                  <strong class="wel">Welcome&nbsp;</strong><strong class="bm"><%= session.getAttribute("userName") %></strong><br>
                   <a href="Login.jsp">Logout</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2>View Transaction</h2>
                </td>
            </tr>               
                <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" 
                      cellspacing="2">
                    <tr class="field_name">
                        <td><div align="center"><strong>Rent ID</strong> 
                     </div></td>
                        <td><div align="center"><strong>Vehicle No.</strong> 
                    </div></td>
                        <td><div align="center"><strong>SP Name</strong> 
                    </div></td>
                        <td><div align="center"><strong>Pickup Date</strong> 
                    </div></td>
                        <td><div align="center"><strong>Return Date</strong> 
                   </div></td>
                        <td><div align="center"><strong>Rent Days</strong> 
                     </div></td>
                        <td><div align="center"><strong>Rent Price</strong> 
                          </div></td>
                        <td><div align="center"><strong>Total Rent</strong> 
                          </div></td>
                        <td><div align="center"><strong>Current 
                         Mileage</strong></div></td>
                        <td><div align="center"><strong>Gas Level</strong> 
                        </div></td>
                        <td><div align="center"><strong>Rent Status</strong> 
                             </div></td>
                        <td><div align="center"><strong>Reserved By</strong> 
                          </div></td>
                        <td colspan="2"><div align="center"> 
                        <strong>Action</strong></div></td>
                    </tr>
                     <%
                     while(rs.next())
                     {
                        rs.getInt("Rent_iD");
                    %>
                    <tr class="view_field">
                        <td><div align="center"><%=++count %></div></td>
                        <td><%= rs.getString("Vehicle_Number") %></td>
                        <td><%= rs.getString("SP_Name") %></td>
                        <td><%= rs.getString("Pickup_date") %></td>
                        <td><%= rs.getString("Return_Date") %></td>
                        <td><%= rs.getString("Rent_days") %></td>
                        <td><%= rs.getString("Rent_Price") %></td>
                        <td><%= rs.getString("Total_Rent") %></td>
                        <td><%= rs.getString("Current_Mileage") %></td>
                        <td><%= rs.getString("Gas_Level") %></td>
                        <td><%= rs.getString("Rent_status") %></td>
                        <td><%= rs.getString("ReservedBy") %></td>
                        <td><div align="center"><a 
                        href="Update.jsp">Update</a></div></td>       
                    </tr>
                </table>    
            <tr>
                <table border="0" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="footer">
                        <ul class="footer_ul">
                        <li><a href="Admin.jsp">Add Car</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Delete.jsp">View Service Request</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="Update.jsp">Update Request</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ViewTransaction.jsp">View 
                      Transactions</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td class="footer">

                      </td>
                   </tr>

                   </table>
                   </tr>
                 </table>
                </body>
               </html>
```

this is the code that we were trying to run in netbeans IDE and when we run it through jsp with the use of apache tomcat server, all it does was just  to display the raw file of the code when running it into a localhost. Where did we go wrong? Or which part of the code went wrong and why did it displayed only raw code or file? Thank you very much.

and the web.xml file goes here..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.servlet.loginServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>validate</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.servlet.validate</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
       <servlet>
             <servlet-name>query</servlet-name>
             <servlet-class>org.servlet.query</servlet-class>
       </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>validate</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/validate</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>query</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/query</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
      <session-timeout>
           30
      </session-timeout>
     </session-config>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: if you remove the page imports above  <!DOCTYPE HTML> and then try refresh the page, what happens? Also, how exactly are you reaching this page? what is the url you are trying to reach?

Comment: Through a localhost. Im running it on the netbeans and when the netbeans run it it will automatically redirect to a page with localhost and port and its jsp page

Comment: yes i understand it's through localhost, but what is the URL in the browser?

Comment: Localhost:8383/nameoffolder/viewrequest.jsp

Comment: ok, so have you tried my first suggestion and removing the page imports?

Comment: Yes I did. Still, it display raw file/code inside the html.

Comment: apparently the problem lies with your tomcat configuration rendering your html as plain text. This might have something to do with your web.xml also.. please post your web.xml

Comment: the comment box wont just allow the whole code to fit in

Comment: Dude.... edit your answer and post the web.xml there.